# Building a C++ project across different branches

Tags: c++, build

My project has more than 1000 files. In this let's say there is a file A.cpp & A.h. When I move to a new branch on my machine & I compile, it compiles everything including A.cpp  even though I had just compiled A.cpp on an old branch.
I heard some companies while downloading cpp files also downloads the corresponding .obj & .lib files, there by speeding up the compilation very fast .
Is this true? What is it called so that I can to incorporate it

I started with https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/improving-compilation-times-c-cpp-projects but the ideas there are not on this line of thought.

Comment: If a file wasn't modified between branches, it won't be recompiled, if your build system does incremental builds in the first place. But you might be interested in [ccache](https://github.com/ccache/ccache) and the like.

Comment: Yes some companies also "download" compiled artifacts. When they build a branch they also put artifacts in a database where they can be copied to your local machine. This is very useful for big repositories since building can take a long time.  E.g : https://blog.packagecloud.io/what-is-artifactory/

Comment: Another good way to improve build times is to create clear interface header files (header file with abstract base classes only, and using the pimpl pattern). That way you can compile files using those interfaces and implementing them in parallel.

Comment: @PepijnKramer it seems jFrog will help in keeping my builds but how will I make visual studio understand that it can get the compiled binary in jFrog repository and that it should not compile?

Comment: I think you need to use a package manager for that and store those in Artifactory e.g. Conan packages or NuGet packages (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/NuGet+Repositories). But I don't know the details of setting that up. From a design point of view, split up your big project into smaller ones (with SDKs) have them build/tested and then stored as packages in Artifactory